# oracle statspack can’t install,what should I do

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

**My environment：**

```
centos6(64bit)
oracle 11g R2 (11.2.0.1.0)
```

**My opration**

```
1.create tablespace

CREATE TABLESPACE statspack
DATAFILE
    '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/tbs_statspack.dbf' SIZE 100M
AUTOEXTEND ON EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 128K
```

> it is succeed!

```
2. run spcreate.sql script

@?/rdbms/admin/spcreate.sql

the problem happend! this script can't run. 
the command line hang on, The cursor blink
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Finally! I solved this problem.
the reason is that set below value in $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql.

```
set termout off
```

remove it, it's OK